# Java API and code for querying TSDB with millisecond resolution

Tags: opentsdb

I have to query the TSDB with millisecond precision.By default when using the TDSBQuery (obtained via TSDB.newQuery()) this requirement is not fulfilled. I tried with TSQuery but it didn't work. The returned results are far more than the ones returned by HTTP query API (that brings the right data that I need):
http://localhost:9999/api/query?start=1197849600.001&end=1197849882.000&msResolution=true&m=sum:CP101_X&ms. 
Can you please help on how to achieve the millisecond precision query by using Java API?

Thanks,
  Regards,
 Florin

I have used the following Java code:

```
TSQuery q = getMetricForValidate();
 q.validateAndSetQuery();
Query[] queries = q.buildQueries(tsdb);
         for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++)
            {
                DataPoints[] dps = queries[i].run();
                if (dps.length > 0)
                {
                    for (DataPoint dp : dps[0])
                    {
                        System.out.println(dp.timestamp());
                    }
                }

            }


 private static TSQuery getMetricForValidate()
    {
        final TSQuery query = new TSQuery();
        query.setStart("119784960.0001");
        query.setEnd("1197849882.000");
        query.setMsResolution(true);

        final ArrayList<TSSubQuery> subs = new ArrayList<TSSubQuery>(1);
        subs.add(getSubMetricForValidate());
        query.setQueries(subs);

        return query;
    }

    public static TSSubQuery getSubMetricForValidate()
    {
        final TSSubQuery sub = new TSSubQuery();
        sub.setAggregator("sum");
        sub.setMetric("01CP101_X");
        sub.setRate(false);
        return sub;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While debugging the TSDMain class, I found out that the filtering at millisecond is not performed at the database level, but in client code in HTTPJsonSerializer. I believe that this is the current supported implementation. Are any other solution at horizon?
Regards,
 Florin